# How to save listbox items to notepad

Tags: vb.net-2010

sorry for the "stupid" question. I can't get the value from the txtbox in the listbox. Now it gives "07650" in the listbox while it's supposed to be 76,50...

I have a function called formatdecimal. If I save (save button) the textfile(to .txt) the value must be saved as "07650" else it must be given like "76,50" in the listbox...

Can someone help me?

`    Public Function FormatDecimal(ByVal perc As Decimal) As String

```
    Return (perc * 100).ToString("00000")

End Function` (Source code for the function)
```

Following is source code from the add button...

```
    Private Sub btnToevoegen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnToevoegen.Click (add button)
    Dim line As String = ""
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim name As String = ""
    Dim Birthday As Integer
    Dim prompt As String
    Dim title As String = "FAILURE"
    Dim perc As Decimal


    If Not CheckLeegtextvak() Then
        MessageBox.Show("Give a value in the textbox", "FAILURE", MessageBoxButtons.OK) 
        Return
    End If (check if the textboxes are empty)

    'If defaultvalues are okay then do something.
    If Not checkdefaultwaarde() Then
        prompt = "Select a value in the combobox."
        MessageBox.Show(prompt, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Return
    End If (check if defaultvalues are okay (beginning of the file)

    CheckLengteNaam() (check the length of the name)

    number = CInt(txtNumber.Text)
    name = CStr(txtName.Text)
    Birthday = CInt(txtBirthday.Text)
    perc = CDec(txtPercentage.Text)


    line = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString.PadRight(1) & number.ToString.PadRight(5) & name.ToString.PadLeft(5) & birthday.ToString.PadRight(5) & perc.ToString.PadLeft(5)
```

lstOutput.Items.Add(line)

```
    FormatDecimal(perc)

End Sub
```

When I add the record, the value of perc must be 76,50. When i save the form to txtfile the value must be 07650 (That's where the function is for) but it doesn't save the right value. It saves "76,50".

Save and save as code...

```
Private Sub mnuBestandOpslaan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuBestandOpslaan.Click (This is the save button)
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim perc As Decimal

    'Zoeken naar opgegeven map om bestand in op te slaan onder dezelfde naam.
    If dlgOpen.FileName = "" Then
        mnuSavefileAs_Click(sender, e)
    Else
        FileOpen(1, dlgOpen.FileName, OpenMode.Output)
        For index = 0 To lstOutput.Items.Count - 1
            PrintLine(1, lstOutput.Items(index))
        Next
        FileClose(1)
    End If

    FormatDecimal(perc)
End Sub

Private Sub mnuBestandOpslaanAls_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuBestandOpslaanAls.Click (This is the save as button) 
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim perc As Decimal

    'Search folder to save file.
    With dlgSave
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\My Documents"
        .Filter = "tekstbestanden (*.txt) | *.txt"
        .Title = "Save as"
    End With

    'Save file.
    If dlgSave.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        FileOpen(1, dlgSave.FileName, OpenMode.Output)
        For index = 0 To lstOutput.Items.Count - 1
            PrintLine(1, lstOutput.Items(index))
        Next
        FileClose(1)
    End If


    FormatDecimal(perc)
End Sub
```

The maximum that you may give as a number is 100 as in 100%...

Comment: Where's the code that writes to the file?...

Comment: Are the things I edited the things you need? Can you help me plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...calling `FormatDecimal(perc)`, by itself on its own line, doesn't actually do anything useful.  I doesn't change any variables and doesn't control formatting in any way.

You're storing a STRING in your ListBox, which makes it difficult to change the format of anything in it when you want to output it to the file.  A better approach would be to create a CLASS to hold those values and override it's ToString() function so it displays correctly in the ListBox.  Now you can add instances of that class to your ListBox.  When you go to print, then, you can format each individual value from the class instance however you want.

EDIT: Here's an example of what I mean...

First, add a Class to your project:

```
Public Class MyData

    Public number As Integer
    Public name As String
    Public Birthday As Integer
    Public perc As Decimal
    Public comboBoxValue As String

    ' This will be used by the ListBox:
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return comboBoxValue & number.ToString.PadRight(5) & name.PadLeft(5) & Birthday.ToString.PadRight(5) & perc.ToString.PadLeft(5)
    End Function

    Public Function ToStringForPrinter() As String
        Return comboBoxValue & number.ToString.PadRight(5) & name.PadLeft(5) & Birthday.ToString.PadRight(5) & (perc * 100).ToString("00000")
    End Function

End Class
```

I don't know what comboBox1 was representing, so you'll have to rename that accordingly and update the code below that accesses it.

Next, when adding items to your list box, you'd change this:

```
    number = CInt(txtNumber.Text)
    Name = CStr(txtName.Text)
    Birthday = CInt(txtBirthday.Text)
    perc = CDec(txtPercentage.Text)
    line = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString.PadRight(1) & number.ToString.PadRight(5) & Name.ToString.PadLeft(5) & birthday.ToString.PadRight(5) & perc.ToString.PadLeft(5)
    lstOutput.Items.Add(line)
```

to something more like this, which creates an instance of MyData and adds it to the ListBox (instead of a string as before):

```
    Dim data As New MyData
    data.comboBoxValue = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString.PadRight(1)
    data.number = CInt(txtNumber.Text)
    data.name = txtName.Text
    data.Birthday = CInt(txtBirthday.Text)
    data.perc = CDec(txtPercentage.Text)
    lstOutput.Items.Add(data)
```

Finally, when printing, you'd change this:

```
    FileOpen(1, dlgOpen.FileName, OpenMode.Output)
    For index = 0 To lstOutput.Items.Count - 1
        PrintLine(1, lstOutput.Items(index))
    Next
    FileClose(1)
```

To something more like:

```
    FileOpen(1, dlgOpen.FileName, OpenMode.Output)
    For Each data As MyData In lstOutput.Items
        PrintLine(1, data.ToStringForPrinter)
    Next
    FileClose(1)
```

Comment: I don't know how to make it work with a CLASS ... Is there any other way... :-S. Thnx for the help!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me at all :-(... You mean work with an array in the created class or.. And how do I do that? My knowledge isn't that good to do this... :).

Comment: Wow okay that does make sense :D. I didn't know you could resolve the problem like this. I'll try it and let you know how it works :D!

Comment: Let me know...this approach also has the benefit that you can grab the selected item in the ListBox and you have all the associated data together because it's actually an instance of MyData in the ListBox.

Comment: It works for the value but now I have a problem with my comboboxes. I need the value of my 3 comboboxes. For example if I choose the values in the comboboxes it should say INF(Department) 1INFb and then the rest like nummer.tostring... in the listbox. If I add the comboboxes it only gives a numeric value instead of "1INFb"... What did I do wrong?

Comment: How are you adding the ComboBox values?

Comment: as this... `data.comboboxvalue = cboDepartment.SelectedItem.ToString.PadRight(5) & cboDepNumber.SelectedIndex.ToString & cboDepartment.SelectedIndex.ToString & cboKDepLetter.SelectedIndex.ToString`

Comment: So with the first ComboBox you're accessing the SelectedItem() property, but the others you're only using SelectedIndex() which is simply the index number of the selected item, not the item itself.  See the difference?  Model the other ComboBox accesses after the first one...

Comment: One more question... Sorry :). What if I want the value when I open it in the form back in decimal form. It saves as 07600 but when I open it, it has to be 76,00 again. Is that also with the tostringPrinter value or...?

Comment: I would open another question about how to open up your text file and **PARSE** it to create instances of MyData.